# Missing Controller Exception for webroot subFolder

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, controller, routes, cakephp-3.0

I uploaded and saved images into /webroot/uploads/xxx/xxx.jpg.

And then I deleted the image file, but it shown in error.log

> 'Error: [Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingControllerException] Controller
>   class Uploads could not be found.'

I think I need to fixed routing, .htacess or something else.

But I don't know how to fixed it.

My Cakephp version is 3.x.x.

Anyone, Could you explain how to fixed them.

Answer (score 2):

@Manohar's suggestions are fine, and the explanation is indeed that CakePHP is mapping missing `/uploads` requests to a controller that doesn't exist. But I always find that understanding the true cause of the problem helps to solve it, as well as avoiding similar problems in the future, so here's a little bit about *why* it does that.

Take a look at `webroot/.htaccess`. It should look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This means that any URL for a resource that is not present (in your case, an image that has been deleted) will be rewritten (internally) to `index.php`, which in turn handles requests through a controller and action determined from the original URL. Since your URL starts with `/uploads`, it will send that to the `UploadsController`.

That all being said, another way to handle your issue is to tell Cake *not* to try to deal with `/uploads` URLs. Simply add something like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads/` after the `RewriteCond` that's already there to tell it not to run the rule for anything starting with `/uploads/`. (Google for mod_rewrite documentation to understand more.)

It's also possible (untested) that simply putting

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

in `webroot/uploads/.htaccess` (which presumably doesn't currently exist) will take care of it, though this might have performance implications (it's an extra file that would need to be loaded and parsed for every request involving `/uploads`).

Note that these options will result in 404 status codes being sent back for any deleted images that your pages might reference, meaning they'll show up as the "missing image" icon. @Manohar's "file_exists" (or any other programmatic solution that avoids even generating the image tag in the HTML) will not do this. Which result is preferable depends on your situation.

Comment: I would vote up for your nice explanation..but making  RewriteEngine off would generate other issues. It would even stop other url working. So this is not good idea !

Comment: The suggestion is ways to turn off rewriting for the `/uploads` URLs only, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

*Well you have deleted xxx.jpg image from that path, but I guess you are still calling that image from somewhere.*

> *Whenever you reload any page which include deleted file then such error exists in error.log file.*

So before giving src(source) to any image/file make sure that exists:

```
if (file_exists(/webroot/uploads/xxx/xxx.jpg)):

endif;
```

Or you can use [CakePHP file library](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/file-folder.html) to handle such situation.

Comment: Thanks sir. But I calling that image for show. That's truth. 
But when I download that file, it gone an error.

Comment: Yes of course that error exists because file is already deleted..So whenever image exists then only you need download right ? So you can use above condition for doing that.

Comment: That means if a file isn't exist, cakephp think as "uploads" folder is controller.
So, is it became Missing Controller Exception ?

Comment: Thanks. I got it.